# Selecting records based on other records using separate date/time fields

Tags: sql

I have a database that stores date and time in separate fields. I need to select all records that occurred within + and - 90 minutes of the date and time each of these happened.

I am able to get everything in the format I need to pull it off

```
SELECT UFV1.USR_DATE
,UFV1.USR_TIME
,LEFT(CAST(DATEADD(minute, -90, UFV1.USR_TIME) AS TIME),8) AS MIN_TIME
,LEFT(CAST(DATEADD(minute, +90, UFV1.USR_TIME) AS TIME),8)AS MAX_TIME
FROM USR_Y_FACILITY_VISIT UFV1

WHERE UFV1.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = '2'

ORDER BY UFV1.USR_DATE, UFV1.USR_TIME
```

Where I am stuck is I need to build a query that takes this info (basically the min/max from each line) then selects all the info in the same table based off that. Thank you for your help I am totally stumped as to where to go next.

Comment: I am not sure if saving date and time separately is a good idea. Is there any special reason to store it this way? Anyway, asper the business rules what happens if the time is 12:30 AM? Does it become 11:00 PM of the previous day when you subtract 90 minutes? Or does it become 12:00 (midnight)?

Comment: Are you concerned with 90 min period crossing the boarder of two consecutive dates?  Would it be a problem if a record is shown as pared to itself (as we do not know how many records have exactly the same date/time combination)?  Do you by any chance have any unique key in the table?

Comment: This unfortunatly the way the system was designed not by myself. The times that would be in there should never cross dates (usually 4-9 or 10)  I would have to cross am/pm but it is stored in 24 hour clock time

here is an example


USR_DATE USR_TIME MIN_TIME MAX_TIME
2012-07-31 00:00:00.000 21:33:58 20:03:58 23:03:58
2012-07-31 00:00:00.000 21:35:23 20:05:23 23:05:23
2012-08-02 00:00:00.000 19:23:31 17:53:31 20:53:31
2012-08-02 00:00:00.000 21:04:59 19:34:59 22:34:59
2012-08-07 00:00:00.000 20:57:56 19:27:56 22:27:56
2012-08-10 00:00:00.000 21:17:40 19:47:40 22:47:40

Comment: sorry for the bad format of the example but it looks right when I edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the key fields for the table to your query as given, along with a corresponding GROUP BY clause. Then query your data table joind to that query as a sun-query on this format:

```
SELECT * 
FROM T
JOIN ( SELECT * ... ) U 
     ON U.key = T.key 
    AND T.dateTime BETWEENU.MinDateTime AND U.MaxDateTime
```

Comment: Pieter Geerkens - You make assumptions that are not grounded in OP's description.

Comment: @PM: That can happen, but I am not seeing it. Could you provide a hint on where I am miunderstanding?

Comment: (1) You're assuming that OP has rights to add a column.  (2) You assume that there is `dateTime` field while OP explicitly stated that s/he has separate fields for Date and Time.

Comment: @PM: You have misunderstood my comment and the original post. (1) I specifically say add "to your query". (2) The OP already seems to have properly combined the date and time fields, and asks how to proceed from there.

Comment: Again, what makes you think that `key` field exists?  OP have not combined date and time - s/he merely subtracted/added minutes.  S/he have not include Date field into his expressions at all.

Comment: @PM (2) OKAY, you read that more carefully than I did. (1) If the key field(s) don't exist the selection is impossible; plus the table would fail 1st NF; there's no rason to assume either without any evidence.

Comment: There is no key field in this its just basically a record of scan times.

Comment: as for the data there is a customer id in each line that I will be joining off to get additional information I am just stuck on how I take these date and times and turn them into meaningful information (over 100 lines for the 1 test case I'm using)

Comment: @user2136646: So your question reduce to "How to add date field to time field to get a datetime field?" Why didn't you just say so?

Comment: Thats not my question.  Maybe this is easier I need to find info for check-ins within + or - 90 min of one specific person checking in (the master_customer in my query above)  sometimes they can check in once a day sometimes more then once but the constant is I need to go back to the same table and select all the check-ins that occoured within + or - 90 min of the time.  There is an option witch isn't ideal but I can use it for this case if I have to have it there is a Date/time field that looking at the data from what I have seen match's the split date time vendor says it doesn't always but.

Comment: Since I ran over the character limit then what I plan on doing with this is use the new customer id's it generates for me to get those peoples info..  the center though is 1 specific person's check-ins.

Comment: Person a checks in at 3pm  and 7pm today and 1:30pm tomorrow I need to find everyone that checked in today between 1:30 to 4:30 and 5:30 to 8:30 and tommorow 12:00 to 3:00. does that make any more sense?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood a question then, this request is necessary for you

```
SELECT *
FROM USR_Y_FACILITY_VISIT UFV1
WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT 1
              FROM USR_Y_FACILITY_VISIT UFV2
              WHERE UFV2.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = '2'
                AND UFV1.USR_DATE = UFV2.USR_DATE
                AND UFV1.USR_TIME BETWEEN CAST(DATEADD(minute, -90, UFV2.USR_TIME) AS time) 
                                    AND CAST(DATEADD(minute, 90, UFV2.USR_TIME) AS time) 
              )
```